# mongodb remove array from the collection using index or any method

Tags: mongodb, express

I have the following collection :

[image: order]

I use the following code to remove the element of the orderList array that matches the orderId. But it doesn't work.

Order.update({"_id":ObjectId(userOrder._id)},{"$pull":{"orderList":{orderId: "WPN-1645691337205"}}});

and I tried the following code as well

Order.update({"_id:":ObjectId("621741dcd40da387489093c2")}, {$unset : {"orderList.0" : 1 }});

Order.update({"_id:":ObjectId("621741dcd40da387489093c2")}, {$pull:{"orderList":null}});

Thanks,
Jo

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Order.update(
  { _id: ObjectId(userOrder._id)},
  { $pull: { orderList: { orderId: "WPN-1645691337205" } } },
  function(error, response) {}
);
```